# reducing whitespace to 1 space between words

Tags: r, text, text-mining, gsub

I have a list of facebook posts from which I have removed symbology.  Now I am left with gaps between the text - 2 or more spaces, which I would like to condense.  How can I remove the extra whitespace so that there is only one space between words?  Also, how could one remove all capital letters that stand by themselves in the text?

```
> head(posts)
[1] "Syntel Recruitment Drive in this week for FRESHERS   New Registration Link 2016 for 2013 2014 2015 Passout Graduates Qualification   Any Graduate B E B Tech MCA M E M Tech Syntel Registration Link"            
[2] "Dont Miss This Opportunity to be get placed in one of the best MNC companies in the world   eBay freshers this week of January 2016  Qualification   Any Graduate Can Apply   eBay Registration Link"            
[3] "Recent Pass Outs with 55  or More are eligible to Apply in  Wipro   Go to the Updated Link for  LastDay Reference Drive  Jan 2016  Apply Link for  Fresher  Referral  Apply Link"                                
[4] "Robert Bosch Recruitment Drive in this week for FRESHERS   New Registration Link 2016 for 2013 2014 2015 Passout Graduates Qualification   Any Graduate B E B Tech MCA M E M Tech Robert Bosch Registration Link"
[5] "Mega  JOB  OPENINGS  OF  THE  YEAR  Mphasis Recruitment for FRESHERS January 2016 Qualification   BE  B Tech  B Sc  BCA  Any Graduates  MCA  MBA  ME  M Tech  Post Graduates  Mphasis Registration Link"         
[6] "TRIGENT Recruitment Drive in this week for FRESHERS   New Registration Link 2016 for 2013 2014 2015 Passout Graduates Qualification   Any Graduate B E B Tech MCA M E M Tech Trigent Registration Link"  


> dput(head(posts))
c("Syntel Recruitment Drive in this week for FRESHERS   New Registration Link 2016 for 2013 2014 2015 Passout Graduates Qualification   Any Graduate B E B Tech MCA M E M Tech Syntel Registration Link", 
"Dont Miss This Opportunity to be get placed in one of the best MNC companies in the world   eBay freshers this week of January 2016  Qualification   Any Graduate Can Apply   eBay Registration Link", 
"Recent Pass Outs with 55  or More are eligible to Apply in  Wipro   Go to the Updated Link for  LastDay Reference Drive  Jan 2016  Apply Link for  Fresher  Referral  Apply Link", 
"Robert Bosch Recruitment Drive in this week for FRESHERS   New Registration Link 2016 for 2013 2014 2015 Passout Graduates Qualification   Any Graduate B E B Tech MCA M E M Tech Robert Bosch Registration Link", 
"Mega  JOB  OPENINGS  OF  THE  YEAR  Mphasis Recruitment for FRESHERS January 2016 Qualification   BE  B Tech  B Sc  BCA  Any Graduates  MCA  MBA  ME  M Tech  Post Graduates  Mphasis Registration Link", 
"TRIGENT Recruitment Drive in this week for FRESHERS   New Registration Link 2016 for 2013 2014 2015 Passout Graduates Qualification   Any Graduate B E B Tech MCA M E M Tech Trigent Registration Link"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `gsub`, you could try

```
posts <- gsub(" +", " ", posts)
```

This will replace every set of adjacent spaces with a single space.